# Function Calls Between GameScene and GameViewController using SKSprit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I writing a program in swift, and am having trouble understanding the proper communication between GameScene and GameViewController:

Basically I have 'savefiles' which are plists, when loaded using a function "self.loadFromPlist(fileName: )" are loaded by clearing the previous array of nodes, and drawings a set of SKShapeNodes based on attributes from the dictionary elements of the loaded Plist

I needed a file browser, which I've implemented from a Cocoapod (FileBrowser), that must be called in the "GameViewController"

My Problem is this:

When calling my 'loadFromPlist' function from inside 'viewDidLoad' like this (to initialize the project) - the function works and the gamescene is drawn:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            
            // Present the scene
           view.presentScene(scene)
            
           let gameScene = scene as! GameScene
            
           gameScene.loadFromPlist(scoreFileName: gameScene.defaultScore)
           gameScene.gameViewControllerDelegate = self
        }
        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}
```

When I try to do same thing in my own function in the GameViewController (called view a GameviewDelete in GamScene), the code executes the line and I can follow it with the debugger into the 'loadFromPlist' function in the gamescene, it executes the for loop drawing shapes etc, but it just does nothing.

```
func callloadplist() {
    
    var loadedfilename2:String!
    
    let file = FileBrowser()
    present(file, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    if let scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size) as? GameScene {

        var strippedfilename: String?

        file.didSelectFile = { (file: FBFile) -> Void in
            let loadedfilename = file.displayName

            scene.filebrowserselectedfilename = loadedfilename

            if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
                // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
                if let myskscene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                    // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window

                    let gameScene = myskscene as! GameScene
                    let strippedfilename = String(loadedfilename.dropLast(6))

                    print(strippedfilename)
                    
                    gameScene.loadFromPlist(scoreFileName: "output")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the function call working inside of 'viewDidLoad()' and also as 'self.loadFromPlist(fileName: )' in GameScene.swift, but cannot be called from a custom method/ function I've made in GameViewControllers -- Any Insights?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So file.didSelectFile is setting up a closure to respond to the event of the file being selected. This was then running the function called on a different instance of a 'GameScene' Object.

I was able to refine my question and answer it here:

[Swift - SKSprite Kit - Change Gamescene Variables from FileBrowser Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63293018/swift-sksprite-kit-change-gamescene-variables-from-filebrowser-closure)