# Swift - SKSprite Kit - Change Gamescene Variables from FileBrowser Closure

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, skspritenode

I am working on an application that uses the 'FileBrowser' CocoaPod to load files in a simulator (using the SKSprites Physics Engine)

I have a function in my GameViewController that creates a 'FileBrowser' instance, then allows the user to set it's 'didSelectFile' closure like so:

```
let file = FileBrowser()
    present(file, animated: true, completion: nil)

fileBrowser.didSelectFile = { (file: FBFile) -> Void in
print(file.displayName)}
```

This enables me to trigger that small bit of code in the closure once a file has been selected from the popup browser, and to print the name of the file clicked, but I can't figure out how to get the value of 'file.displayName' back to my GameScene (I need it to be passed to that class instance to load the file and change the level, etc).

I've tried adding a 'String' return to the closure, which I cannot do. I've also tried to pass my GameScene to the Closure but that doesn't work.

So how do I get the data that is retrievable within that closure back to my GameScene if I cannot edit the closures inputs / outputs? (they are defined by the library).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem:

What I had to do was give the GameViewController class a property 'scene', and then add inside of the "viewDidLoad()" function:

```
self.scene = gameScene
```

then inside the closure, I had to add the code

```
let gameScene = self.scene as! GameScene
```

Then I could edit variables in my GameScene (ex: gameScene.numberofpoints = 100)

So in short, I guess giving the GameViewController class a 'scene' variable to store the gamescene, then allowed me to change attributes of this gameScene from within the closure.